# Mongodb/Mongoose Query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, coffeescript, mongoose

A `User` has a bunch of `Essays`, stored as an array of ObjectIds. In CoffeeScript, the schema is:

```
User = new Schema
  essays: [Schema.Types.ObjectId]
  name: String

Essay = new Schema
  grade: Number
  text: String
  author: Schema.Types.ObjectId
```

How do I get all distinct users whose latest essay was written in the last day, and whose **latest essay's grade is between 80 and 90**, in one query?

I've got this (in CoffeeScript):

```
req.mongoose.Essay
  .find(
    _id:
      $gt:
        # trick which creates an ObjectId with yesterday's timestamp
        mongoose.Types.ObjectId.createFromHexString(
          (~~(yesterday.getTime() / 1000)).toString(16) +
          "0000000000000000"
        )
  )
  .where("grade").gt(80).lt(90)
  .popluate(path: "User")
  .exec (err, docs) ->
    console.log ({name: essay.author.name} for essay in docs)
```

This is close but not quite.

This will get anyone who has written an essay in the last day where the essay's score is between 80-90. So for example, if I wrote an essay two hours ago and scored an 85, but then wrote an essay 1 hour ago and scored a 50, I would show up - but I shouldn't because my **latest essay** (which was written within the last day) did not score between 80-90.

Also, this will get duplicates if someone wrote two essays in the last day and got an 85 on both. Note that `distinct` doesn't work in conjunction with `populate` on the same field.

This query is too broad. I need to get everyone whose **latest essay** (which must be written in the last day) is between 80-90.

Comment: Using `ObjectId` to determine insertion date is not a very good idea, it's best to store this information explicitly (e.g. in `created` field).

Answer (score 2):

The only way I can think of is to form an array of all last `Essay`s `_id`s by querying `User` collection:

```coffee
req.mongoose.User
  .find(essays: $not: $size: 0) # Just to be sure
  .select(essays: $slice: -1) # We only interested in last Essay
  .lean() # It's faster
  .exec (err, users) ->
    ids = users.map ({essays}) ->
      # essays array contains exactly one [last] element
      essays[0]
    .filter (_id) ->
      # We only interested in yesterday Essays
      _id.getTimestamp() >= yesterday
    req.mongoose.Essay
      .find(_id: $in ids)
      .where('grade').gt(80).lt(90)
      .popluate('User')
      .exec (err, docs) ->
        console.log ({name: essay.author.name} for essay in docs)
```

Note that it also allows me to properly filter fetched `ids` to compare they generation dates with `yesterday` date using [`ObjectId::getTimestamp` method](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/objectid.html#gettimestamp).

Comment: I was afraid this was impossible in one query. Thanks for the response.